# Error en tutorial para uso de flask-login

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para saber cómo se trabaja con `flask-login` para el control de usuarios en una aplicación flask, es el siguiente:

[Link al tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-authentication-to-your-app-with-flask-login)

Una vez que he creado todos los archivos, cuando intento generar la base de datos con las líneas:

```
>>> from project import db, create_app
>>> db.create_all(app=create_app())
```

Obtengo el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

La primera pregunta que tengo es:

¿Cuando se especifica el nombre de la carpeta que contiene el archivo `__init__.py`, es decir `project` en vez de hacer referencia implícita con `from __init__ import...` los objetos y métodos se obtienen de dicho archivo por defecto?

He comprobado ejecutando lo siguiente y sin ningún problema:

```
>>> from __init__ import db, create_app
```

Ahora bien, cuando intento crear la base de datos a partir de la configuración de la aplicación `app` obtengo el siguiente error:

```
>>> db.create_all(app=create_app())
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\project\__init__.py", line 16, in create_app
    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

La siguiente cuestión es que no puedo importar los objetos de los archivos auth.py ni main.py haciendo referencia con .auth y .main

Este es el esquema del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La versión de Python que estoy utilizando es la `3.8.2`

Comment: Gracias por comentar @FJSevilla, por defecto Visual Studio Code pone la carpeta principal en mayúsculas en el árbol de proyecto, el nombre de la carpeta está en minúsculas.

Comment: Vale, descartado esto, ¿cuál es el directorio de trabajo del interprete interactivo cuando haces `from project import db, create_app` (`import os; print(os.getcwd())`
)? Debe ser el directorio dónde está la carpeta project,  no `project` mismo.

Comment: El problema es que no puedo importar desde `project`, ejecuto todo con:
`(env) PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\project> python`
Y obtengo el error comentado.
Con `import os; print(os.getcwd())` devuelve `C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\project`
Perdón si no he comprendido bien la pregunta.

Comment: Debes hacer `C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\> python` y ahora podrás importar project. Tal como lanzas el intérpete éste tiene como directorio de trabajo la ruta al propio `project`, cuando debe ser la de  su padre, `Python`.

Comment: De acuerdo, no tenía constancia de este hecho. Muchas gracias, si quieres modifico la pregunta con cómo lanzo los comandos y respondas corrigiendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La excepción:

> ```
> >>> from project import db, create_app
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
> ```

se debe a que la **ruta de trabajo de tu intérprete interactivo** no es **la misma que la de la carpeta `project`**.

Por ejemplo, si tienes la estructura:

> ```
> Desktop
> |
> |--Python
>    |
>    |--project
> ```

debes abrir el intérprete con la ruta a la carpeta `Python` como directorio de trabajo, no con `Python/project`. Puedes también cambiar el directorio de trabajo desde el propio intérprete:

> ```
> $ C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\> python
>
> >>> import os
> >>> os.chdir("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Python")
> >>> from project import db, create_app
> ```

Ahora la segunda duda,

> ¿Cuando se especifica el nombre de la carpeta que contiene el archivo `__init__.py`, es decir `project` en vez de hacer referencia implícita con `from __init__ import`... los objetos y métodos se obtienen de dicho archivo por defecto?

`project` es lo que se conoce como paquete ordinario ("regular package") ya que contiene un archivo `__init__.py`, al contrario que los paquetes de espacio de nombres ("namespace packages").

Dicho archivo es **usado para inicializar paquetes** y es **ejecutado cuando se importa el paquete de forma automática**, cuando haces:

```
import project
```

el intérprete ejecuta su `__init__.py` en primera instancia y por tanto todo su espacio de nombres global queda expuesto en el paquete. En este caso la variable global `db` y la función `create_app` son accesibles y referenciables desde el espacio de nombres `project`.

Por último:

> ```
> >>> from __init__ import db, create_app
> >>> db.create_all(app=create_app())
> File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Python\project\__init__.py", line 16, in create_app
>     from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
> ```

El problema es que `__init__.py` no está pensado para ser importado o ejecutado directamente, sus imports relativos no lo están. Cuando importas el archivo directamente el interprete no sabe que forma parte de un paquete o no a no ser que importes referenciando el paquete:

> ```
> >>> import os
> >>> os.chdir("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Python")
> >>> from project.__init__ import db, create_app
> ```

los imports relativos solo se pueden usar dentro de un paquete (tradicional o de espacio de nombres). Obviamente lo anterior no tiene mucho sentido, ya que el `__init__.py` precisamente está pensado para permitir importar mediante:

```
>>> from project import db, create_app
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y la explicación.